# Trouble building NVIDIA VisionWorks (OpenVX) on Windows

Tags: build, nvidia

I am attempting to install VisionWorks on Windows as described in the link named "VisionWorks 1.0 for Windows README" on this page:
https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/visionworks

According to the README document VisionWorks is compatible with Windows with the following configuration:

```
OS       : Windows 8 x64
OpenCV   : public OpenCV 2.4.12
CUDA     : NVIDIA CUDA 7.0
```

I am using exactly this same configuration with the following variables as described in the README (with my specific PC's paths):

```
[CUDA_VERSION]            : 7.0
[CUDA_INSTALL_DIR]        : C:\cuda\v7
[OpenCV_INSTALL_DIR]      : C:\opencv
[OpenCV_VERSION]          : 2412
[VisionWorks_VERSION]     : 1.0
[VisionWorks_INSTALL_DIR] : C:\cuda\VisionWorks
[SAMPLES_BUILD_DIR]       : C:\cuda\VisionWorks\SAMPLES_BUILD_DIR
```

I follow the directions in the README as seen below (**Images at end of post**):

**Step 1:**
Copy samples from [VisionWorks_INSTALL_DIR]\share\visionworks\sources to a
directory with write access [SAMPLES_BUILD_DIR].

**Step 2:**
    Open Visual Studio's Developer Command Prompt - VS2013 x64 Native Tools
    Command Prompt.

**Step 3:**
        Go to the [SAMPLES_BUILD_DIR]:

```
    > cd [SAMPLES_BUILD_DIR]
```

**Step 4:**
        Edit the config.nmake file to insert correct paths for all prerequisite
        installation directory information.

```
    # Dependency locations
    CUDA_DIR = [CUDA_INSTALL_DIR]
    OPENCV_DIR = [OpenCV_INSTALL_DIR]\build
    OpenCV_VERSION = [OpenCV_VERSION]
    VISIONWORKS_DIR = [VisionWorks_INSTALL_DIR]

    # Debug build?
    dbg = 0
```

**Step 5:** 
        Build samples using nmake

```
    > nmake
```

But when I execute the nmake command I get the following error:

```
C:\cuda\VisionWorks\SAMPLES_BUILD_DIR> nmake
```

> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> cd nvxio && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\ amd64\nmake.exe" / /nologo build
>   if NOT EXIST "obj\release" mkdir "obj\release"
>           cl /EHsc /O2 /MD /nologo "-DVISIONWORKS_DIR=\"C:/cuda/VisionWorks\""  -D USE_GUI=1 -DUSE_GLFW=1
>   -I./include -I./shaders  -I../3rdparty/opengl -I../3rdpa rty/freetype/include -I../3rdparty/glfw3/include -I./src
>   -DUSE_OPENCV=1 -I "C:\c uda\v7\include" -I "C:\opencv\include" -I "C:\cuda\VisionWorks\include" -I "..\3 rdparty\eigen" 
>   /Fo"obj\release\" /c src\Application.cpp src\ArgumentParser.cpp 
>   src\ConfigParser.cpp src\OptionHandler.cpp src\Utility.cpp
>   Application.cpp
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(109)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(118)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(127)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(136)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all' ArgumentParser.cpp
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(109)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(118)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(127)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(136)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all' ConfigParser.cpp
>   ./include\NVXIO/OptionHandler.hpp(109) : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range
>   nvxio::ra nges::all(void)' : could not deduce template argument for
>   'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   ./include\NVXIO/OptionHandler.hpp(118) : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range
>   nvxio::ra nges::all(void)' : could not deduce template argument for
>   'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   ./include\NVXIO/OptionHandler.hpp(127) : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range
>   nvxio::ra nges::all(void)' : could not deduce template argument for
>   'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   ./include\NVXIO/OptionHandler.hpp(136) : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range
>   nvxio::ra nges::all(void)' : could not deduce template argument for
>   'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all' OptionHandler.cpp
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(109)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(118)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(127)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all'
>   c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\OptionHandler.hpp(136)
>   : error C2783: 'nvxio::Range nvxio::ranges::all(void)' : could not
>   deduce te mplate argument for 'T'
>           c:\cuda\visionworks\samples_build_dir\nvxio\include\nvxio\Range.hpp(163)
>   : see declaration of 'nvxio::ranges::all' Utility.cpp Generating
>   Code... **NMAKE : fatal error U1077:** '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 12.0 \VC\BIN\amd64\cl.EXE"' : **return code '0x2'** Stop.
>   **NMAKE : fatal error U1077**: 'cd' : **return code '0x2'** Stop.
>
> C:\cuda\VisionWorks\SAMPLES_BUILD_DIR>

[Images showing the steps I performed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwx8S.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is a bug (more a feature lacking implementation) in the VS 2013 compiler. Function template parameters are only deduced based on types in the arguments, so a call with no arguments will not trigger deduction.

The rather ugly workaround for VisionWorks is to replace the template in Range.hpp

```
/*
 * \ingroup group_nvxio_range
 * \brief Creates a range that includes all points.
 * \return The range.
 */
template <typename T>
inline Range<T> all() {
    return { std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest(), std::numeric_limits<T>::max(), true, true };
}
```

with a template with a dummy argument, and fix the uses in OptionHandler.hpp accordingly.

```
/*
 * \ingroup group_nvxio_range
 * \brief Creates a range that includes all points.
 * \return The range.
 */
template <typename T>
inline Range<T> all(T dummy) {
    return { std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest(), std::numeric_limits<T>::max(), true, true };
}
```

so that the calls in OptionHandler.hpp looks like

```
static ptr real(float *result, const Range<float> &validRange = ranges::all<float>((float)1));
```

So this makes the code pretty fugly, and defeats somewhat the purpose of the template. This templating issue is fixed in VS 2015, but CUDA doesn´t compile in 2015, which makes more advanced use of OpenVX pointless.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you Asbjørn.